# Register a web app that can serve as API in Azure AD

Tags: reactjs, azure, web, next.js, azure-active-directory

I have a question about setting up a web application that can be accessed from other clients like SPA applications.
How should I set it in Azure AD? How to solve the auth step in the flow?
My idea was to have a web app registered (web redirect, application id, scopes) so it can be both a web app and by getting token from `app://clientID/scopes` requesting anything from the app, but I am not sure if that's correct. Any suggestions?

EDIT: What's the flow for it and why? How to manage it on the server? Verify the token each time? Set sessions?

Answer (score 0):

In order to setup access via Azure Active Directory for a Single Page web application

1. Create **Azure AD Tenant**
2. **Register Web Application**
3. **Set up authentication** settings in the registered application, specifying redirect URIs and allowed grant types.
4. **Define required API permissions** for your application in the **"API permissions"** tab.
5. **Configure the Application ID URI** and audience for your API in the "Expose an API" tab.
6. Allow cross-origin requests from your single-page application domain on your web application server or using Azure App Service CORS settings.
7. **Implement Authentication in SPA via MSAL.js.** Use it to handle authentication in your single-page application, configuring it with the client ID and other details.

Comment: that's something I know of - mentioned in a question. I am looking for more detailed explanation, but thanks for trying. I need to know how to auth both on web app as well as from other spa. What's the flow for each and why